# Four types of mediators

Tags: oop, design-patterns, class-diagram, mediator

I often encounter the problem of choosing the interaction pattern in many-to-many relationships. The following example demonstrates four different ways to achieve the same goal.

The goal is to deliver a message (advertisment) from one group of entities (`DeliveryCompany`, `College`, `Supermarket`) to another (`LazyBob`, `CleverAnn`, `FastJon`). Obviously, we need a mediator (`AdBoard`) which will help both publishers with delivering their ads to appropriate person and subscribers with notifying them about interesting proposals.

Responding to ad is out of concerns right now, but if it matters, we can assume that it will be necessary in future. Anyway, this respond must have a different path (we're not responding to ads with another ad, right?)

**First:**

All subscribers must implement the interface describing their differences. Mediator is injected with them and implement an interface for publishers' purposes.

[image: Mediator-1]

**Second:**

Reverse version of first. Now publishers implement an interface describing their preferences. It is used by mediator which implement an interface for subscribers' purposes.

[image: Mediator-2]

**Third:**

Mediator implements two interfaces: for sending targeted advertisment (back-end) and for receiving an ad on interesting topic (front-end). Back-end injected into all publishers, front-end injected into all subscribers.

[image: Mediator-3]

**Fourth:**

Reverse version of third. Now mediator is injected with a number of publishers and subscribers which implement their interfaces.

[image: Mediator-4]

**Question**:

Did these variants reached the goal with same success?

At early stage of development each of it can be chosen without any doubts, right or not? If not, what is the algorithm of choosing?

Comment: Can you explain the difference of them? What are the decision you are unsure of?

Comment: Differences should be clear from diagrams, but I'll add some explanation in a minute. I'm unsure which one to choose. Should I just flip a coin twice? What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to minimize coupling, ideally the Companies and the JobSeekers just use an interface to the `AdBoard`, but they don't need any structural changes.

If however it is essential that a JobSeeker can subscribe (and it is essential that you model this now), then you need the `IAdSubscriberInterface`, and the `AdBoard` needs to aggregate the Subscribers.

If JobSeekers are just looking at the `AdBoard` when they have some time, the `AdBoard` needs to know nothing about JobSeekers.

Unless there is some a business-relationship, the `AdBoard` may also not need to know anything about AdPublishers.

What is missing in the pictures is the Ad. The `AdBoard` aggregates the Ads. The Ad probably needs some information about the AdPublisher. It can hold an association to the AdPublisher.
Or if you want to further minimize coupling, the required information like company name are just copied into the Ad at creation time, like it is also done with paper-based Ads.

Comment: Honestly, too much here I do not agree / not understand. Let's start from the beginning. "Given that you want to minimize coupling, ideally the Companies and the JobSeekers just use an interface to the AdBoard" - you mean the 3rd variant, don't you? But why it is less coupled than others?

Comment: It is less coupled, because the Companies are not required to implement the IAddPublisherInterface just to use the AdBoard.

Comment: You mean that implementing interface is somehow harder than using interface? But why? If we follow ISP then class which uses some interface must call each member and "walk through" all invariants of implementor at some time. The same as implementor must implement all members and satisfy all invariants.